# Beamer: Same vertical space between items in nested lists

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate, itemize

For some reason, if I try to nest lists, the vertical space between the list items is not the same anymore; the one above the first item of the nested list and the one below the list item of the nested list do not match up.

[image]

This issue does not seem to be solved by using an empty line as in [this issue](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/530). Does anyone have an idea?

MWE

```
\documentclass[leqno,hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Eine Gruppierung der mengentheoretischen Axiome}
Die mengentheoretischen Axiome lassen sich in zwei Gruppen aufteilen:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Grundlegende Axiome
\item Etwas Längeres als das 

\begin{itemize}
\item Das Extensionalitätsaxiom
\item Das Unendlichkeitsaxiom
\end{itemize}
\item Axiome, die erlauben, aus \textit{existenten} Mengen neue zu gewinnen
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```